# Create a -1, 0, 1 matrix from two data frames

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create a matrix with the values -1, 0, and 1 for expression data. The issue I'm encountering is the data is in two separate data frames, one contains over-expression and the other under-expressed. I would like to combine them into the same column with over-expressed terms showing a "1", under-expression a "-1", and no change a "0".

```
>over
0.09
0.08
0.02
0.10
0.07
>under
0.07
0.03
0.06
0.01
0.02
```

So I would like a matrix that gives a `1` for <0.05 in `over` and a `-1` for <0.05 in `under`:

```
>new
0
-1
1
-1
-1
```

Tried a couple different things, but keep hitting walls and haven't been able to find anything specific in the form of a similar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a couple of basic assignments:

```
# recreate your data
over  <- c(0.09,0.08,0.02,0.10,0.07)
under <- c(0.07,0.03,0.06,0.01,0.02)

out <- vector("numeric",5)
out[over  < 0.05] <-  1
out[under < 0.05] <- -1
out
#[1]  0 -1  1 -1 -1
```

Or shorthand using `interaction` to check multiple conditions. Which has the added advantage of dealing with cases that meet both criteria and labelling them as such. It also allows arbitrary labelling.

```
c(0,1,-1,2)[interaction(over < 0.05, under < 0.05)]
#[1]  0 -1  1 -1 -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just directly use the comparisons on each data frame themselves and treat them as numeric.  This will result in only 0 or 1 values.

```
mat <- as.matrix(as.numeric(df1$over < 0.05) -
       as.numeric(df2$under < 0.05))
> mat
      [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]   -1
[3,]    1
[4,]   -1
[5,]   -1
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(over=c(0.09, 0.08, 0.02, 0.10, 0.07))
df2 <- data.frame(under=c(0.07, 0.03, 0.06, 0.01, 0.02))
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way than this but you could bind the columns together, create a `new` column filled with 0s, test for the "over" and "under" conditions then convert the `new` column to a matrix, all using `dplyr`. Of course if both conditions can be true then the second test will overwrite the result of the first.

```
library(dplyr)
new <- over %>%
  bind_cols(under) %>%
  mutate(new = 0) %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(over < 0.05, 1, new)) %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(under < 0.05, -1, new)) %>%
  select(new) %>%
  as.matrix()

new
     new
[1,]   0
[2,]  -1
[3,]   1
[4,]  -1
[5,]  -1
```

Comment: Maybe `case_when`: `data_frame(over, under, new = case_when(over < .05 ~ 1, under < .05 ~ -1, TRUE ~ 0))`

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this without converting to `numeric`

```
new <- (df1$over < 0.05) - (df2$under < 0.05)
dim(new) <- dim(df1)
new
#      [,1]
#[1,]    0
#[2,]   -1
#[3,]    1
#[4,]   -1
#[5,]   -1
```

---

Or another option is

```
matrix(Reduce(`-`, lapply(cbind(df1, df2), `<`, 0.05)))
```